# How to pass a variable to the body (not header/params) of a sampler

Tags: groovy, jmeter-plugins, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I have a request from where I am getting a token in response. I have captured that token into a variable using Regular Expression Extractor-Post processor.

Now, I want to pass this token to the body of the next sampler in two places, one as the contributionID and the second as the contrib_(pass the value).mp4
This is how the body looks:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09vqN.png)

The problem is, passing it via header manager is not working. And passing variable in body causes syntax error.

It seems that I would need to pass it using beanshell script or something else which I am unable to implement.

Any leads?

I have tried adding beanshell preprocessor in the sampler where I want to pass the value but I am unable to capture the body and the respective parameter.

It would be a huge help if I could get a hint towards a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think just variable named: **contributionId** in **Regular Expression Extractor-Post processor** then in body request

```
{
 ....
"contributionId": "${contributionId}",
"file": ....,"":"contrib_"${contributionId}".mp4"}]
}
```